# Passing Javascript Object Array to MVC Controller w/ POST

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I have an array of javascript objects that is constructed using JQuery across multiple table rows. It has the following form:

```
obj_rows = [
    {"param1":value11, "param2":value12, "param3":value3},
    {"param1":value21, "param2":value22, "param3":value23},
    //more objects with the same parameters
]
```

What I would like is a way for an AJAX POST request to a Controller method SomeController/SomeAction that takes in this array and can iterate over all objects. I was trying to figure out a way to do this using JSON, but to no success.

NOTE: Even though I am using MVC, I do not have a model class corresponding to these objects. Ideally, I would like to end up with some structure like a List of 3 Tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the solution is to take the object and stringify it into a string and then send it over the ajax request.

just do:
`JSON.stringify(obj_rows)`
and you will get on the other endpoint an array (stringified of course), you have to parse it back and you will have your array.

Comment: So if I just use data:JSON.stringify(obj_rows) in my POST request, how should I write my Controller method? SomeController(Object[] obj_rows)?

Comment: @D.Jones it depends on your controller language. for example in node it would be easy as `JSON.parse(obj_rows)`

Comment: I see. Thank you for this!

Comment: @D.Jones if you think this was correct, mark it as the answer, if you need more info, don't hesitate on asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript method JSON.stringify() to convert you object into a string and assign its result to a hidden field in your view and once you recieve this in your controller  you can then deserialize it to an object or parse it yourself.